# Does the "Azoth Attuned" bag mod work when you gain 1 azoth?

Tags: new-world

This bag mod gives you 3.0%-4.8% more azoth. However most azoth from gathering is gained 1 at a time, so does this bag mod even work for that case? Does it track decimal values of azoth without showing the player?

Comment: If I had to guess, there is probably some sort of round down logic it does when you gain any azoth from gathering.  So 4.8% of 1 would be 1.048, rounded down is just 1 again.